# How to improve query performance with OR or IN operators in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Item table with 1.8 millons of rows:

```
Item
-----------
- id
- title
- content
- channel_id
```

and a Channel table with 8000+ rows:

```
Channel
-----------
- id
- name
```

What i need is shows items from a channel called "global" in every result, for example i have the following channels:

```
id    |    name
________________
1     |    global
2     |    restaurants
3     |    hotels
...
```

so I have tried the following consults:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE channel_id = 1 OR channel_id = 2 ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 10
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE channel_id IN (1, 2) ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 10
```

Both of them take around 18 seconds! ...and there are already two indexes for id and channel_id

**Update**

Looks the problem is the ORDER BY clouse and not the OR or IN operators, there are too many items to order.

**Update**
I have fixed this creating a index for title:

```
CREATE INDEX item_by_title ON item (title ASC)
```

Comment: 18 seconds is rather slow for only ~2m rows (assuming you aren't returning a lot of rows, which might tie up the sorting). How fast does it run if you just do `WHERE channel_id=1`? What if you remove the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: I've just tried. it takes 17.5 seconds... I am lost. Some suggestion?

Comment: So `SELECT * FROM Item WHERE channel_id = 1` takes 17.5 seconds? How many rows are you actually returning? I am not too familiar with pgSQL, but if you are returning more than about 5% of the rows some RDBMS won't use indexes and will just do a full table scan instead.

Comment: the full query was: SELECT * FROM Item WHERE channel_id = 1 ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 10

Comment: i'm going to have to agree that this doesn't make much sense.  Can you add the DDL for your index definitions on *both* the item and chanel tables?    Is this a dev server or one with lots of other activity? How many items have Chanel_ID 1 ? 2?

Comment: To the OP: can you show us the plan for the original query ? Just put "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" before the query.

Comment: I would try to add the field 'title' to the index on 'chanel_id'. That might make it possible to fetch the rows already ordered and it can quit after 10 rows instead of having to fetch all of them and doing a sort on all matches.

Comment: At least that is what I would do in SQL Server. Don't know if it is possible in PostgreSQL. If PostgreSQL is smart enough to combine two separate indexes you could try to add a new index on 'title'.

Comment: Please run an `EXPLAIN ANALZYE`and upload the execution plan to http://explain.depesz.com/ and post the link to the uploaded plan.

Answer (score 1):

By ordering by title you are forcing a final sort step for 1.8M tuples, just to get the top 10 records.
Try sorting on id, for example.

Comment: -1 This is not true. The filtering using `WHERE` occurs *before* `ORDER BY` is used.

Comment: Well depends on how many records pass the filtering, I don't know his data.Maybe the original poster could show the query plan. Or test his query without the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I removed the downvote, but this doesn't look quite right. If the query is returning 1.8M rows, it doesn't really matter if you sort on id or title

Comment: Hi, I've just tried without the ORDER BY clouse. It takes 0.162 ms ...I think the problem is the ORDER BY... but i need to to order by title.

Comment: Well, the reason for this is that for a (table or index) scan+filter the (sub)query can be abandoned once the LIMIT is reached by the outer query.